# Error when retrieve data from mongodb on web service

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc

My json data in mongodb

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(2), "_class" : "hello.Record", "cameraid" : "001", "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-15T14:45:21.982Z"), "filename" : "yhao.png" }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(3), "_class" : "hello.Record", "cameraid" : "002", "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-15T14:45:21.982Z"), "filename" : "ydd.png" }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(4), "_class" : "hello.Record", "cameraid" : "003", "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-15T14:45:21.982Z"), "filename" : "ddds.png" }
```

This is my model class

```
  public class Record {
  private long id;
  private String cameraid;
  private DateTime timestamp;
  private String filename;


public Record(long id, String cameraid, String timestamp, String filename) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cameraid = cameraid;
    this.timestamp = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(timestamp);
    this.filename = filename;
}
//getters & setters
```

This is my controller class.

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/camera")
public class RecordController {
@Autowired
RecordRepository rep;

@RequestMapping(value="list")
public List<Record> getList() {
    return rep.findAll();
}
```

This is my MongoRepository class.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface RecordRepository extends MongoRepository<Record, String> {

}
```

Error i got in spring:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Error when i run my url on the browser

```
Failed to instantiate hello.Record using constructor public hello.Record(long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) with arguments 2,001,2015-06-15T22:45:21.982+08:00,yhao.png
```

Anyone got an ideas why i having this error?? i think the error is with the datetime format.

Comment: Do you need explicitly define the constructor? Let JPA handle it by reflection on setters.

Comment: Meaning??Like how?

Comment: What @TheCoder means is you can remove constructor from `class Record`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Record` to this;)

```
public class Record {
    private Long id;
    private String cameraid;
    private DateTime timestamp;
    private String filename;


    public Record(Long id, String cameraid, String timestamp, String filename) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cameraid = cameraid;
        this.timestamp = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(timestamp);
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: i tried this method too. Still the same error ( Sorry i forget to update my model class)

Answer (score 0):

Make the constructor argument types match field types exactly:

```
public class Record {
  private long id;
  private String cameraid;
  private DateTime timestamp;
  private String filename;

  public Record(long id, String cameraid, DateTime timestamp, String filename) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cameraid = cameraid;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.filename = filename;
  }

  //getters & setters
}
```

And as TheCoder said in the comments, if you don't use the constructor explicitly, you may just remove it, Spring will use fields/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly define the constructor. I suppose it's due to mismatched argument type (something like that). So remove the constructor and let the JPA handle `ResultSet -> Bean` conversion by reflection on setters.

```
public class Record {

    private long id;
    private String cameraid;
    private DateTime timestamp;
    private String filename;

    // getters of all fields
    // setters of id, cameraid, filename

    // Not sure whether this will work, coz Argument datatype is diff from field datatype.
    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(timestamp);
    }

    // If the above doesn't work, comment above setter and uncomment below setter.
    // Also you don't need to handle String result to Datatime conversion manually, 
    // coz JPA is capable of converting result value to appropriate DataType 
    // (But does it support Datatime datatype..?)
    /*public void setTimestamp(DateTime timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }*/

}
```

Comment: But i need to define the constructor for my controller

Comment: @KevinKai, Have you tried changing the Datatype of timestamp from `String -> Datatime` in your constructor and what's the result? Like the answer proposed by @Roman

Comment: yeah i tried. i now got a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694686/convert-datetime-format-from-web-service-to-a-string?noredirect=1#comment62869099_37694686