# Convert datetime format from web service to a string

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, datetime

This is my POM.xml .. Error is Overriding managed version 2.8.2 for joda-time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service-cors</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My json data on web service

```
 [{"id":2,"cameraid":"004","timestamp":{"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2016,"yearOfCentury":16,"weekyear":2016,"monthOfYear":11,"weekOfWeekyear":48,"dayOfMonth":29,"dayOfWeek":2,"era":1,"dayOfYear":334,"year":2016,"millisOfSecond":0,"millisOfDay":5521000,"secondOfMinute":1,"secondOfDay":5521,"minuteOfHour":32,"minuteOfDay":92,"hourOfDay":1,"zone":{"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"},"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"},"millis":1480354321000,"chronology":{"zone":{"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"},"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"}},"afterNow":true,"beforeNow":false,"equalNow":false},"filename":"ogh.png"}
,{"id":3,"cameraid":"002","timestamp":{"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2015,"yearOfCentury":15,"weekyear":2015,"monthOfYear":6,"weekOfWeekyear":25,"dayOfMonth":15,"dayOfWeek":1,"era":1,"dayOfYear":166,"year":2015,"millisOfSecond":982,"millisOfDay":81921982,"secondOfMinute":21,"secondOfDay":81921,"minuteOfHour":45,"minuteOfDay":1365,"hourOfDay":22,"zone":{"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"},"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"},"millis":1434379521982,"chronology":{"zone":{"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"},"fixed":false,"id":"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"filename":"ydd.png"},
```

My model class:

```
public class Record {

@Id private Long id;
private String cameraid;
private DateTime timestamp;
private String filename;


public Record(Long id,String cameraid, DateTime timestamp, String filename) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cameraid = cameraid;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.filename = filename;
}
```

My controller class:

```
@Autowired
RecordRepository rep;

@RequestMapping(value="list")
public List<Record> getList() {
List<Record> recordList = rep.findAll(); 
return recordList;
```

MongoRepository class:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface RecordRepository extends MongoRepository<Record, String> {

}
```

How to display the timestamp as this format (2016-07-16T19:20:30+01:00) on the web service?

Comment: Which JSON converter/framework you are using to convert the Pojo to Json e.g. Jackson, Gson or anything else?

Comment: Also can you tell me which DateTime class you are using is it from Joda

Comment: i using json and i using joda-time

Comment: It might be as simple as adding a dependency on [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) to your project. If it's a Spring Boot application, it will be registered automatically; if not, you might need to register the module yourself.

Comment: @Jesper After i added dependency, what should i do next? Sorry im new to spring.

Comment: Not related to question, but if you are using Java 8, you should use Java's Date Time api introduced in 8. Joda home page also suggests the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Use Jackson Serializers - For global conversion. Applied to every conversion
2. User Spring WebDataBinder and PropertyEditorSupport . You can choose which controller need this conversion

**Implement Jackson serializer**

Register above class to Jackson Module

```
public class CustomDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {
    // Customize format as per your need 
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator generator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(formatter.print(value));
    }

}
```

Add Serializer to Jackson Module

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JodaModule jacksonJodaModule() {
        final JodaModule module = new JodaModule();
        module.addSerializer(DateTime.class, new CustomDateTimeSerializer());
        return module;
    }
}
```

**Use WebBinder API and PropertyEditorSupport**

Implement PropertyEditorSupport

```
public class DateTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public DateTimeEditor(String dateFormat) {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat);
    }

    public String getAsText() {
        DateTime value = (DateTime) getValue();
        return value != null ? value.toString(formatter) : "";
    }

    public void setAsText( String text ) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if ( !StringUtils.hasText(text) ) {
            // Treat empty String as null value.
            setValue(null);
        } else {
            setValue(new DateTime(formatter.parseDateTime(text)));
        }
    }
}
```

Add this PropertyEditor to Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public class AbcController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, new DateTimeEditor("yyyy-MM-dd", false));
    }

}
```

Comment: On the JodaModule, i having error. It does not revolve as a type

Comment: it is part of jackson-datatype-joda

Comment: @KevinKai `JodaModule` is in [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda), you have to add that as a dependency in your project.

Comment: Yeah i added. Is the version make any difference?

Comment: it might. Which version you are using

Comment: I using version 2.4.0

Comment: When i add the dependency into pom.xml and i got an error saying : Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.32

Comment: Strange. Can you post your pom.xml. Add it to question

Comment: The pom posted works at my side. Can you check if this works from command line by executing `mvn package`

Comment: @SangramJadhav even if i did not add dependency for jackson datatype, i still be able to import the rest except for JodaModule.